# Flutter ListView separators showing after filtering data

Tags: flutter

The below ListView displays a list of data which displays properly with a separator below each item, but when the list is filtered, the dividers still show.

```
Expanded(
        child: ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return filter == null || filter == ""
                  ? ListTile(
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                      title: Text(
                        list[index].title,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        _edit(list[index].docid);
                      },
                    )
                  : list[index].term.toLowerCase().contains(filter)
                      ? ListTile(
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                          title: Text(
                            list[index].title,
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            _edit(list[index].docid);
                          },
                        )
                      : Container();
            }),
        // ),
      ),
```

** Edit **

Since I wanted to have my list displayed and filtered when something was typed in a search box, I used the correct answer's code like this:

```
Widget _renderList() {
    List filteredList;

    if (filter != null && filter != '') {
      filteredList = list
          .where(
            (item) =>
                item.term.toLowerCase().contains(filter),
          )
          .toList();
    } else {
      filteredList = list.toList();
    }
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
          itemCount: filteredList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                title: Text(
                  filteredList[index].term,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  _editTerm(filteredList[index].docid);
                },
              )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView.seperated(...) creates a fixed-length scrollable linear array of list "items" separated by list item "separators".

In your code, when you apply a filter, and an item does not match the filter, it is rendered as an empty Container. This container is still a list item, albeit an empty one. So, ListView will render seperator for it as well.

To tackle this scenario, pass a filtered list to the ListView.

Refactor your code as follows

```
Widget renderList() {
    List filteredList = list
        .where((item) => filter != null && filter != '' && item.term.toLowerCase().contains(filter))
        .toList();
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
              Divider(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
          itemCount: filteredList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            title: Text(
              filteredList[index].title,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              _edit(filteredList[index].docid);
            },
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed your code a little to fit my use case.